# JavaScript function if url has hash tag and user has just navigated forward or back with browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, navigation

The following will fire an alert when the page is refreshed if the hash tag ends in `twoB`:

```
if (window.location.href.match(/\#twoB/))
{
   alert('twoB');
}
```

The issue is that if you've clicked on a few hash tags and then click back in your browser, although the URL includes the hash the alert doesn't fire. How can I make the code fires (ideally only) after a user has gone back or forward with their browser.

I'm using jQuery for this project so i would like a jQuery solution in an ideal world if the syntax is easier.

Comment: You're looking for one of the many jQuery history plugins.

Comment: Is their no native way to do this? Seems a shame to use a library for one feature if it can be done without. Thanks

Comment: @jdn See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Ive answered my question using something sort of similar. #tag links are already added to the browser history, so the issue was firing something when their clicked, there isnt a need to modify the browser history. Ive solved it with onpopstate which listens for when the history changes, such as when you click a #tag. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if ive used the correct terminology, by #tag links I mean link fragments eg <a href-"#frag">Link to content on this page</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I solved this quite an ugly way of using setInterval to repeatedly check the URL. HTML5s 
onpopstate runs when the page is first loaded and then every forward and back navigation aswell.

```
window.onpopstate = function(){ 
  if (window.location.href.match(/\#twoB/))
  {
     alert('twoB');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function () {
    console.log("hash is now " + window.location.hash);
});
```

Note that `on` was added in jQuery 1.7; if you're using an older version, then do `$(window).bind` instead.

Comment: Just noticed it also breaks any JavaScript below it. Is there a syntax error? Ive only added your code exactly how it is, do I need to define "hashchange" or something? Thanks

Comment: Hmm, no, it should work... I'm assuming you have jQuery as the `$` global?

Comment: Here is my solution. It works as far as ive tested but does depend on onpopstate and would be pretty annoying for users without it.   http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/1/

Comment: Here is my probably wrong implementation of your code. Ive also tried putting in the jquery function before the gmap3 function, but still doesnt work for me. Thanks  http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/2/

Comment: Try $(window).bind instead of $(window).on. It could be a JQuery version issue as .on was added in version 1.7.

Comment: @roto good catch! From the example he posted he is indeed using an older version.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use location.hash instead of href.match? The location.hash should be faster as you are only getting the hash and you don't have to do a match?

Comment: Does this solve my problem or just improve performance? Thanks for the tip either way.