# How to embed an iFrame with a URL with a '#' in it in a simplemodal box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I am trying to do something the following:

```
$("#link_id").click(function() {
    $.modal('<div class="framed-view"><iframe src="http://domain.com/stuff#12"/></div>');
            });
```

Using the jQuery simplemodal plugin.

However, when I click that link - the link that is displayed is:
http://domain.com/stuff

rather than

http://domain.com/stuff#12

Does anyone know why the iframe would be ignoring everything after the hash tag?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this HTML is in JavaScript and must be properly escaped when certain characters conflict with standard JS characters.

Escape the hashtag using `\` as this user did. [JavaScript function if url has hash tag and user has just navigated forward or back with browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792159/javascript-function-if-url-has-hash-tag-and-user-has-just-navigated-forward-or-b)

You may also need to escape `/` characters as well.

Comment: Not working in this case - using encodeURI() also didn't do the trick here.

Comment: This might have nothing to do with JS itself and something to do with the simplemodal plugin. What kind of data can it take as a parameter?

Comment: The doc says it can take HTML as an argument. http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: how do you download this thing? The author didn't make the link very easy to find. (I can google, just venting.)